# puppet - what lines get executed?

Tags: puppet

(puppet n00b)

How do I check what lines get executed in a puppet run?

We have a large codebase with many manifests and not all manifests get applied depending on the role of the computer.

How can I check whether a given manifest runs, and subsequently whether "include xyz::zzz" gets run?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the puppet agent will run the catalog it receives from the master, according to his cert name and environment. 
this process is know as "node matching".
check out the site.pp in /etc/puppet/manifests (or /etc/puppet/environment//manifests if you are using environments) on you puppet master, to see which manifests your specific node should run.

Also , you can run the puppet agent with the --debug mode:

```
puppet agent -t --debug
```

if you are still not sure which manifests are being executed, I suggest adding a notify statement in the begging of each manifest -

```
notify{'executing module <module-name>':}
```